# Voiding last approve vote

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues

Sometimes I'm done reviewing an item and it happens that my eye gets caught in one of the small modifications which I totally missed before.. and that usually happens when I'm clicking the <kbd>Approve</kbd> button.

When that modification is wrong, I regret not having a <kbd>Void my last review</kbd> button.

Is this a completely bad idea? I don't happen to know any workaround for this and I'd love to hear if there's one

Comment: Accidents happen, you move on. If they happen too often, be more careful.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sure, but I like rubbers on the top my pencils too :D

Comment: It just doesn't happen all that often to warrant more complexity in the code, is what I mean. Putting those rubbers on top of your pencils takes time and energy too!